# TikZ: How to draw lines between a set of points and their scope-images and fill the enclosed area?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120129/2288), I need to:

1. draw a horizontal line between point `a` and its scope-image, and draw another horizontal line between point `b` and its scope-image
2. fill the trapezoid whose sides are two horizontal lines drawn in the previous step, the line connecting `a` and `b`, and the line connecting the images of `a` and `b`.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta}
    \tikzset{>={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]}}

    \usepackage{environ}
    \NewEnviron{xmirror}[2]{
    \BODY
    \begin{scope}[xscale= #1,xshift=#2]\BODY\end{scope}
    }


    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{xmirror}{-1}{-4cm}
    \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) -- ++(0.4,0) coordinate(a) node[right]{a} -- ++(1,-2) coordinate(b) node[right]{b} -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(-0.2,0) -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(-0.2,0) -- ++(0,0.4) -- cycle ;
    \end{xmirror}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: from example I suspect, that the nodes in mirrored shape are in wrong position (this can not be handled by used approach). lines between `a` and `b` already exist or should be between this two point be double line?

Comment: @Zarko I am sorry, I didn't get your question.

Comment: please, explain (again) what is the problem in image you shopw in question: position of nodes at mirrored shape? filling area between this two shapes? drawing double lines between `a` and `b`? or something else ?

Comment: @Zarko please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: see, if i correctly understood your question :)

Comment: The answer looks great, I will get back to it in minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

differences are in labels. in second case in the code below are deleted:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, backgrounds, calc, 
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                matrix, positioning,}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]}  
         }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) -- ++(0.4, 0) coordinate[label=0:a] (a1) 
                          -- ++(1.0,-2) coordinate[label=0:b] (b1) 
                          -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(-0.2,0) -- ++(0,-0.2)
                          -- ++(-0.2,0) -- ++(0,0.4) -- cycle;
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1, xshift=-4cm]
\draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) -- ++(0.4, 0) coordinate[label=180:a] (a2) 
                          -- ++(1.0,-2) coordinate[label=180:b] (b2)   
                          -- ++(0,-0.2) -- ++(-0.2,0) -- ++(0,-0.2) 
                          -- ++(-0.2,0) -- ++(0,0.4) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\draw (a1) -- (a2)  (b1) -- (b2);
\scoped[on background layer]
\fill[cyan!10]   (a1) -- (b1) -- (b2) -- (a2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately with your approach this is possible only if you by hand determine coordinates `a1` ... `b2`. To my opinion is simpler to copoy shape and than scale and shift as is done above.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an amalgamation of the original approach and Zarko's answer. The main point is to use a macro

```
\somepart[options for scope environment]{name}
```

that draws the yellow part once and labels the relevant positions by `name-a` and `name-b`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\newcommand\somepart[2][]%
  {\begin{scope}[#1]
   \draw[fill=yellow]
     (0,0)
     -- ++(0.4,0) coordinate(#2-a)
     -- ++(1,-2) coordinate(#2-b)
     -- ++(0,-0.2)
     -- ++(-0.2,0)
     -- ++(0,-0.2)
     -- ++(-0.2,0)
     -- ++(0,0.4)
     -- cycle ;
   \end{scope}%
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \somepart{left}
  \somepart[xscale=-1,xshift=-4cm]{right}
  \draw (left-a) -- (right-a)  (left-b) -- (right-b);
  \scoped[on background layer]
  \fill[cyan!10] (left-a) -- (left-b) -- (right-b) -- (right-a) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful answer, but I need to understand something, why does latex **automatically** assign the argument in curly braces of `\somepart{left}` to `coordinate(#2-a)` and  `coordinate(#2-b)`? is it because `#2` inside `coordinate` is a mandatory input and arguments inside curly braces are always understood to be mandatory?

Comment: If a command definition starts with `\newcommand\mymacro[3]{...}`, then it has three mandatory arguments named `#1` to `#3`. If the command definition starts with `\newcommand\mymacro[3][yippie]{...}`, then the first argument (`#1`) is optional and `#2` and `#3` are mandatory. If no optional argument is provided, than `yippie` is used as value of `#1`. Here, `\somepart` is defined as `\newcommand\somepart[2][]{...}`, which means that the first argument is optional (default value is empty) and the second one is mandatory. So  `\somepart{left}` is the same as `\somepart[]{left}`.

Comment: Many thanks for considering my question. So, regarding your example of three arguments, if I defined it as `\newcommand\mymacro[3][ ][ ]{...}`, it would have `#1` and `#2` as optional arguments, while `#3` is mandatory, am I right?

Comment: No, this only works with one optional argument. If you want to have more flexibility, like two optional arguments, use `\DeclareDocumentCommand` from the `xparse` package. See  [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument). To handle your example, you have to write `\usepackage{xparse}\DeclareDocumentCommand\mymacro{oom}`.

Comment: Ohh I see, I appreciate your consideration, and I will take a look at this link. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

`TikZ` defines its own kind of macros and call them `pics`. With `pics`, [gernot's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361909/1952) can be simplified to:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    somepart/.pic={
        \draw[fill=yellow]
            (0,0)
            -- ++(0.4,0) coordinate(-a)
            -- ++(1,-2) coordinate(-b)
            |- ++(-0.2,-0.2)
            |- ++(-0.2,-0.2)
            -- ++(0,0.4)
            -- cycle ;
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic (left) at (0,0) {somepart};
  \pic[xscale=-1] (right) at (4,0) {somepart};
  \draw[fill=cyan!10] (left-a) -- (right-a) -- (right-b) -- (left-b)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Coordinate names defined inside the `pic`, like `-a` and `-b` can be referenced outside the `pic` with a `prefix` formed by the `pic` name: `left-a` or `right-b`.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this simple and clean answer. Out of curiosity, is there a way to label a & b and their images as done in the first output of [Zarko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361903/2288)?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Add the label inside `pic` code:  `coordinate[label=a](-a)`, `coordinate[label=b](-b)`. In this case, as `b` labels are behind the filled part, if you want to see them, place the last command on a background layer: `\begin{scope}[on background layer] \draw[fill=cyan!10] (left-a) -- (right-a) -- (right-b) -- (left-b)--cycle; \end{scope}`.