# TikZ: pic code with multiple \draw commands doesn't compile as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

For the following code,

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta,backgrounds,hobby}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
Nozzle/.pic={
    \draw[fill=yellow]
    (0,0)
    -- ++(0.4,0) coordinate(-a)
    -- ++(1,-2) coordinate(-b)
    -- ++(0,-0.2) coordinate(-c)
    -- ++(-0.2,0) coordinate(-d)
    -- ++(0,-0.2) coordinate(-e)
    -- ++(-0.2,0)
    -- ++(0,0.4)
    -- cycle ;

    \draw[fill=brown] (#1-c)
    -- (#1-d)
    -- (#1-e)
    -- ++(0.4,-0.1)
    -- ++(0,0.1)
    -- cycle;

}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \pic (left) at (0,0) {Nozzle};
    \pic[xscale=-1] (right) at (4,0) {Nozzle};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the output is

[image]

while the desired output should be

[image]

Comment: First, you should remove `#1` in the second draw statement. After that, the code still does not work which is due, I think, to a bug in the implementation of `\pic`. I remember to have read this argument (`\pic` being buggy) also as an answer to other complaints about `\pic` behaving strangely. I recommend to use a macro definition as I have proposed in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: @gernot I put `#1` since I thought it should be after checking [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194370/2288). I tried to follow [Ignasi's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362028/2288), but probably, I will stick to the macro approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct coordinate names inside `pic` are `-c`, `-d`, ... not `#1-c`, ...
If you use them and don't let `cycle` to close the path, your code works for me.

Note: I've deleted `hobby` package due to compiling errors in my system. In any case, it's not necessary for this example.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
    Nozzle/.pic={
        \draw[fill=yellow]
        (0,0)
    -- ++(0.4,0) coordinate(-a)
    -- ++(1,-2) coordinate(-b)
    -- ++(0,-0.2) coordinate(-c)
    -- ++(-0.2,0) coordinate(-d)
    -- ++(0,-0.2) coordinate(-e)
    -- ++(-0.2,0) coordinate(-f)
    -- ++(0,0.4)
    -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=brown] (-c)
        -| (-e)-- ++(0.4,-0.1) -- ++(0,0.1) --(-c);
}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (left) at (0,0) {Nozzle};
    \pic[xscale=-1] (right) at (4,0) {Nozzle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, for me, it works even with loading `hobby`. However, it is really strange that `cycle` doesn't work in the second `draw`. Is it mentioned as a bug in the manual to be fixed later or should I just ignore it and move on?

Comment: Well, you are cheating a bit ... Replace `(-c) -| (-e)` by `(-c) -- (-d) -- (-e)`, which should work as well, and you will note that the area is not completely filled. This pic thing is full of surprises.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution along the lines of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194370/110998). You have to change the following things in your code:

- Add the option `name prefix ..` to the second draw command.
- You have to provide a value for the parameter `#1` by adding it after the name of the pic: `Nozzle=left` and `Nozzle=right`.

.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
Nozzle/.pic={
    \draw[fill=yellow]
    (0,0)
    -- ++(0.4,0) coordinate(-a)
    -- ++(1,-2) coordinate(-b)
    -- ++(0,-0.2) coordinate(-c)
    -- ++(-0.2,0) coordinate(-d)
    -- ++(0,-0.2) coordinate(-e)
    -- ++(-0.2,0)
    -- ++(0,0.4)
    -- cycle ;

    \draw[fill=brown,name prefix ..] (#1-c) % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    -- (#1-d)
    -- (#1-e)
    -- ++(0.4,-0.1)
    -- ++(0,0.1)
    -- cycle;

}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \pic (left) at (0,0) {Nozzle=left}; % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \pic[xscale=-1] (right) at (4,0) {Nozzle=right}; % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for solving it. Could you please tell me where I can find more info on `name prefix ..` and `{Nozzle=left/right}` in the manual?

Comment: Regarding `name prefix ..` see the [Tikz manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) page 255. Read the whole section 18 starting on page 251.