# fontawesome: How to mirror a symbol in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontawesome

In some of my tikz pictures I use symbols from the `fontawesome` package.

**Screenshot**

(The long line of the checkmark should be on the left side.)

[image]

**Question**

How can I mirror symbols in tikz?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Check    
    \draw (0,0) node {\faCheck}; 

    % Rectangle  
    \node [draw, thick, shape=rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=center] at (0,0) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**What I tried so far**

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119940/101831)

```
\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw (0,0) node {\faCheck}; 
\end{scope}
```

doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Try `\draw (0,0) node[yscale=-1,xscale=1] {\faCheck}; `.

Comment: It's `node[yscale=1,xscale=-1]` ;-)

Comment: Fine. From your attempt I concluded you want to reflect at the x axis.

Comment: You can also do `\draw (0,0) node {\reflectbox{\faCheck}};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reflect at the x axis, try`\draw (0,0) node[yscale=-1,xscale=1] {\faCheck};`, and if you want to reflect at the y axis, which makes the long side appear on the left side, use `\draw (0,0) node[yscale=-1,xscale=1] {\faCheck};`. (Source: the very title page of the pgfmanual. ;-)