# tikz - mirror parts with offset

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to mirror below parts by x = 2.5 line (AB), xscale will mirror it by x = 0 line.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \def\parts{(1,1) -- (2.5,3) -- (1,4)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines, dashed] (0,0) grid(5,4);
   \draw[] \parts [xscale=-1] \parts;
   \draw[red] (2.5,1) node[below]{A} -- (2.5,4) node[above]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What's proper way to do such mirror?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This introduces a key `mirror`, whatever you pass to this key will get mirrored. In your figure this amounts to saying

```
\tikzset{mirror={\draw (1,1) -- (2.5,3) -- (1,4);}}
```

There are styles `mirrored` and `unmirrored`, which can be used to change the transformation laws, introducing offsets or also name prefixes, say.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mirror/.code={\tikzset{mirrored stuff/.code={#1}}
    \begin{scope}[unmirrored]
     \tikzset{mirrored stuff}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[mirrored]
     \tikzset{mirrored stuff}
    \end{scope}},mirrored/.style={xscale=-1},unmirrored/.style={}]
  \draw [help lines, dashed] (0,0) grid(5,4);
  \tikzset{mirrored/.append style={xshift=-5cm},
  mirror={\draw (1,1) -- (2.5,3) -- (1,4);}}
  \draw[red] (2.5,1) node[below]{A} -- (2.5,4) node[above]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that there are much more versatile options available like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142491) which I found after completing the example.

Answer (score 0):

xshift helped to fix this issue!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \def\parts{(1,1) -- (2.5,3) -- (1,4)}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [help lines, dashed] (0,0) grid(5,4);
        \draw[] \parts[x={(-1,0)},y={(0,1)},xshift=2*2.5cm] \parts;
        \draw[red] (2.5,1) node[below]{A} -- (2.5,4) node[above]{B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The idea is x-shifting to the origin, then using `[xscale=-1]` to mirror, and x-shifting back. Note: the order of options matters!

The code is corrected from @beetlej.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% object to be mirrored
\def\xmirror{2.5}   
\def\myobject{(1,1) -- (2.5,3) -- (1,4)}
\draw[violet,opacity=.3] (0,0) grid (5,5);
\draw[red] (\xmirror,1) node[below]{A} -- (\xmirror,4) node[above]{B};

\draw \myobject;
\draw[shift={(\xmirror,0)},xscale=-1,shift={(-\xmirror,0)}] \myobject;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```