# Is there a way to draw the rest of a path by mirroring the existing part?

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

Here is a simple path, which has a symmetry:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- ++(-9,0) -- ++(5,3) -- ++(2,7) -- ++(2,0);

\draw[green,thick] (0,10) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(2,-7) -- ++(5,-3) -- ++(-9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now instead of drawing the green part manually, would it be possible to just say `-- mirror cycle` or similar and draw it automatically? I know there are ways as explained in [Can we mirror a part in tikz ("axial symmetry", "reflection")?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119914/can-we-mirror-a-part-in-tikz-axial-symmetry-reflection) but there the path is not continous and it requires an extra environment, where the path is copied, so there is no reduction in maintanence, when the path changes.

Comment: You can store your path in a macro with `\newcommand{\mypath}{...}` and reuse it into the mirror scope.

Comment: Ok, this solves the reuse part, but not the continuous path problem.

Comment: [The last answer to the post you provided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119961/204164) seems to answer your need, but in `pstricks`. I don't think it's feasible in Ti*k*Z without having to dig into the `pgf` layer.

Comment: This looks like the sort of thing that the `spath3` library eats for breakfast.  I'm not on a device where I can cook something up myself, but someone else might be able to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done with `spath3`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[spath/save=apath] (0, 0) -- ++(-9, 0) -- ++(5, 3) -- ++(2, 7) -- ++(2, 0);
\draw[thick, fill=green, spath/use=apath] [spath/transform={apath}{xscale=-1}, spath/use={apath, reverse, move, weld}] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Green filled symmetrical shape]

Comment: Nice solution! Where can I find documentation on that tikz library? I tried to find out more about it on the pgfmanual on CTAN but there was nothing.

Comment: @MarkFantini: You presumably already have the documentation as part of your LaTeX installation - just type `texdoc spath3` in a terminal. -or you can find it here: https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3?lang=en

Comment: Thank you! Will check it. Can I find other docs like this? I'm new to using the terminal by trying other stuff (learning Python and programming), and it could be a game changer to find docs like this instead of going to ctan.org. EDIT: Just tried it and it works! This is amazing!! Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

The mirror axis is at *x* = 0, thus a simple macro with the sign as parameter is a simple solution. Because of the color change, a continuous solution is not possible anyway:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick]
    (0, 0) -- ++(-9, 0) -- ++(5, 3) -- ++(2, 7) -- ++(2, 0)
  ;
  \draw[green, thick]
    (0, 10) -- ++(2, 0) -- ++(2, -7) -- ++(5, -3) -- ++(-9, 0)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A continuous solution is more complicate. For example, the mirrored points can be calculated and stored in a list in reverse order:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newdimen\myX

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myInit}[1]{%
  #1%
  \pgfextra{%
    \global\myX\pgf@x
    \global\let\myList\@empty
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\myNext}[1]{%
  -- #1%
  \pgfextra{%
    \xdef\myList{%
      --(\the\dimexpr2\myX-\pgf@x\relax,\the\pgf@y)%
      \myList
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick, fill=lightgray]
    \myInit{(0, 0)}
    \myNext{++(-9, 0)}
    \myNext{++(5, 3)}
    \myNext{++(2, 7)}
    \myList
    -- cycle
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate handy path operations in Asymptote: `reverse`, `xscale`, etc.

[image]

```
// copy to http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and click Run
unitsize(1cm);
path Lpath=(0,0)--(-9,0)--(-4,3)--(-2,10)--(0,10);   // the left path
path Rpath=xscale(-1)*Lpath;                         // the right path is symmetric with the left to axis x=0   
path mypath=Lpath--reverse(Rpath)--cycle;            // the whole (closed) path
fill(mypath,lightgreen);                            // filling the whole path
draw(Lpath,red+2pt);                                // draw the left path    
draw(Rpath,blue+2pt);                               // draw the right path

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));                       // make the boundary bigger
```

**Update** A more appropriate for the whole path is using `&` connector, as suggested by @NguyenVanChi1998

```
path mypath=Lpath & reverse(Rpath) & cycle;
```

Comment: The operator `&` (Chapter 5: Bezier curves) be a better replacement for your `mypath`.

Comment: Yes, that is right! I added an update for that.